# Building cryptocurrency exchange behind TOR

Tags: exchanges, server, tor

quick question, I don't have much experience with TOR(actually nothing), is it reasonable to build a mobile cryptocurrency exchange, which servers are behind TOR, so that's hard to attack for hackers ?

Answer (score 0):

Tor is just an access network. You can create a service and make it available on any access network, whether exclusively or not. Operating it on Tor exclusively doesn't make it hacker-proof. You need to properly harden the server as well as all access points into your exchange (meaning your executables), and even then there could be vulnerabilities which can lead a hacker to compromise your service.

Comment: I see. You mean that by making it anonymous, the potential attacker can still perform any kind of attack( like dos, CSRF attack ) as effectively as if the service wasn't behind TOR ? Of course the server should be additionally protected is if it were on public, non-anonymous network, my question was more if TOR would be any additional obstacle for an attacker in some hacking techniques, or basically all it gives is anonymity - no hacking-protection at all.

Comment: please have a look  @anion :) at the above comment

Answer (score 0):

possible? yes. reasonable? maybe, depends on your situation. you can use tor to hide the server of every website which you host but usually you use tor only if you have a reason why you want to be anonymous (or want improve the anonymity of your user). tor is no hacking-protection.

Comment: hey @anion, could you please take a look at my below comment ?